# AngularJS - Sending and receiving data but not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a one page app, and I want to have call to the server to query for items of a specific price (for example www.myapp.com/products?price=1200). I am able to execute the request and get the JSON back from the endpoint, but the view doesn't update and show the data. Any ideas of why my view is not updating?

My first thought is that the problem is in the $routeProvider, but I dont know how I need to change it.

Thanks!

My angular module

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.
    when('/products', 
      { templateUrl: 'partials/productSearchTemplate.html',   
        controller: ProductControl
      });
}]);
```

My controller

```
function ProductControl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.sendRequest = function () {
    $http({
        url: '/products', 
        method: "GET",
        query: {price: $scope.price}
    }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.products = data;    
    });
  }
}
```

My view

```
<div class="products">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products" class='product-panel'>
        <div class='front'>                
            <span class='product-title'>{{product.title}}</span><br/>
            <span class='product-manufacturer'>
                {{product.manufacturer}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class='back'>
            <span class='product-price'>
                {{product.price}}
            </span><br/>
            <a href="{{product.url}}">Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: from which point you are calling sendRequest

Comment: I have a button in my index.html page <button id='search-button' class="btn" ng-click='sendRequest()'>Search</button>

Comment: If your button is not within the productSearchTemplate partial then I suspect it has no access to the scope of ProductControl and therefore cannot call sendRequest.

Comment: I already verified that it does by logging the response in the console. The request is sent and received, but the DOM is not updated.

Comment: use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140) to create demo that replicates problem

Comment: Does it work if you put `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.products = data`?  Also, can you post your data so we can validate what your returning.  Try using [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) to view your scope objects, great troubleshooting tool.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your 'products' endpoint doesn't return array, but the object instead. Your expects following json from the server:

```
[
   {"title":"title","price":1,"manufacturer":"Someone"}
]
```

But most likely server returns object instead of array:

```
 {
    "products":[{"title":"title","price":1,"manufacturer":"Someone"}],
    "totalCount": 1 
 }
```

So just check via Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, what is returned from server, and perform necessary conversion in controller.